# copy buffer contents to another buffer

Tags: c++

I have the contents of an http request in my buffer.
I then define another buffer of the same size as the last one.
And i need to copy the contents of the buffer to my new buffer.
So the help i need is that how do i get to copy one buffer to another buffer.

I tried `memcpy` but it is not working.

```
void TrivialMediaPlayer::DeliverMediaData(
        int                         streamId,
        bool                        bHasPriority,
        ConstBufferSptr             pMediaData)
```

What i want is to copy the contents of `pMediaData` to a new buffer.

```
BufferSptr buf1 (new Buffer (pMediaData->Size()) );
```

i want to copy `pMediaData` in `buf1`.

thanks

Comment: memcpy sounds like what you want - can you post a fragment of your code.

Comment: @fammi: This is impossible to answer without knowing the type of your buffer. Please show us the relevant code (definition of the buffer, the code that is supposed to copy it).

Comment: 1. Show your code. 2. Accept answers in your previous questions.

Comment: Please don't say `memcpy()` isn't working unless you provide code and describe observed behavior.

Comment: @fammi: Please show us how you copy the buffer.

Comment: @fammi: Is there a specific reason why cannot just use an `std::vector<char>` as buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what the exact code you write to copy from one StringSptr from another.
But if you wanna

```
memcpy( (void*)buf1 , (void*)pMediaData , pMediaData.Size() );
```

You must make sure that you should defined the "void*" function in the BufferSptr class (seems like a class written by you) to convert your BufferSptr object to a real C pointer which point to the address of internal buffer.
Or, use some explicit call:

```
memcpy( buf1.data() , pMediaData.data() , pMediaData.Size() );
```

Comment: thanks, yes the buffer class is written... i will add it in the original post